# Sort a table with UTF-8 encoded values alphabetically

Tags: sorting, utf-8, lua, locale, alphabetical

I am storing dictionary entries in a Lua table, using it as an array. I want to sort the entries from Lua, so that I can add new ones without having to move to the correct position myself (which gets quite tedious soon). However, I am facing several problems:

1. Many words contain non-ASCII characters, which makes the built-in comparison operator for strings unsuitable for the task (for instance, it makes *amputar* come before *ámbito*).
2. There are words from various languages (all Western, though), namely Spanish, German and English. The problem here is that, probably, different languages have different notions of the alphabetical order. Since the main language is Spanish, I would like to use its rules, although I'm unsure as to whether that will work with characters not contained in the Spanish alphabet.
3. Some words contain capital letters, or, even worse, start with them. For example, all German nouns start with upper-case letters. By the built-in comparison operator, the capital letters come before their lower-case siblings, which is not my desired behaviour; I would like upper-case letters to be treated exactly as their lower-case counterparts.

Take, for example, the following table:

```
local entries =
{
    'amputar',
    'Volksgeist',
    'ámbito'
}
```

Those entries should be ordered like this:

> ámbito
>   amputar
>   Volksgeist

However, with my current code, the output is wrong:

```
local function compare_utf8_strings( o1 , o2 )
    -- Using the built-in non-UTF-8-aware non-locale-aware string comparison operator
    return o1 < o2
end

table.sort( entries , function ( a , b ) return compare_utf8_strings( a , b ) end )

for i, entry in ipairs(entries) do
    print( entry )
end
```

That outputs:

> Volksgeist
>   amputar
>   ámbito

Could you please take the following code, and hack it to fulfill my requirements?

```
local entries =
{
    'amputar',
    'Volksgeist',
    'ámbito'
}

local function compare_utf8_strings( o1 , o2 )
    -- Hack here, please, accomplishing my requirements
end

table.sort( entries , function ( a , b ) return compare_utf8_strings( a , b ) end )

for i, entry in ipairs(entries) do
    print( entry )
end
```

It should output this:

> ámbito
>   amputar
>   Volksgeist

As an additional requirement, this Lua code is all inside LuaTeX, which currently supports 5.2 version of the language. As for external libraries, I guess it's possible to use them.

I am a novice in the Lua camp, so, please, forgive any error I have made, and feel free to notify it, so I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time searching to no avail, I found [this article](http://www.texdev.net/2014/07/08/luatex-manipulating-utf-8-text-using-lua/) by Joseph Wright. Although it touched my issue, it didn't provide a clear solution to follow. I asked him, and it turned out that there's currently no direct way to do what I want. He pointed out, however, that *slnunicode* comes built-in with LuaTeX (albeit it will be replaced in the future).

I developed a 'crude' solution using the facilities provided in the LuaTeX environment. It isn't elegant, but it works, and it doesn't pull any external dependencies. About its efficiency, I have not perceived any difference in the document build time.

```
-- Make the facilities available
unicode = require( 'unicode' )
utf8 = unicode.utf8

--[[
    Each character's position in this array-like table determines its 'priority'.
    Several characters in the same slot have the same 'priority'.
]]
local alphabet =
{
    -- The space is here because of other requirements of my project
    { ' ' },
    { 'a', 'á', 'à', 'ä' },
    { 'b' },
    { 'c' },
    { 'd' },
    { 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ë' },
    { 'f' },
    { 'g' },
    { 'h' },
    { 'i', 'í', 'ì', 'ï' },
    { 'j' },
    { 'k' },
    { 'l' },
    { 'm' },
    { 'n' },
    { 'ñ' },
    { 'o', 'ó', 'ò', 'ö' },
    { 'p' },
    { 'q' },
    { 'r' },
    { 's' },
    { 't' },
    { 'u', 'ú', 'ù', 'ü' },
    { 'v' },
    { 'w' },
    { 'x' },
    { 'y' },
    { 'z' }
}

-- Looks up the character `character´ in the alphabet and returns its 'priority'
local function get_pos_in_alphabet( character )
    for i, alphabet_entry in ipairs(alphabet) do
        for _, alphabet_char in ipairs(alphabet_entry) do
            if character == alphabet_char then
                return i
            end
        end
    end

    --[[
        If it isn't in the alphabet, abort: it's better than silently outputting some
        random garbage, and, thanks to the message, allows to add the character to
        the table.
    ]]
    assert( false , "'" .. character .. "' was not in alphabet" )
end

-- Returns the characters in the UTF-8-encoded string `s´ in an array-like table
local function get_utf8_string_characters( s )
    --[[
        I saw this variable being used in several code snippets around the Web, but
        it isn't provided in my LuaTeX environment; I use this form of initialization
        to be safe if it's defined in the future.
    ]]
    utf8.charpattern = utf8.charpattern or "([%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*)"

    local characters = {}

    for character in s:gmatch(utf8.charpattern) do
        table.insert( characters , character )
    end

    return characters
end

local function compare_utf8_strings( _o1 , _o2 )
    --[[
        `o1_chars´ and `o2_chars´ are array-like tables containing all of the
        characters of each string, which are all made lower-case using the
        slnunicode facilities that come built-in with LuaTeX.
    ]]
    local o1_chars = get_utf8_string_characters( utf8.lower(_o1) )
    local o2_chars = get_utf8_string_characters( utf8.lower(_o2) )

    local o1_len = utf8.len(o1)
    local o2_len = utf8.len(o2)

    for i = 1, math.min( o1_len , o2_len ) do
        o1_pos = get_pos_in_alphabet( o1_chars[i] )
        o2_pos = get_pos_in_alphabet( o2_chars[i] )

        if o1_pos > o2_pos then
            return false
        elseif o1_pos < o2_pos then
            return true
        end
    end

    return o1_len < o2_len
end
```

I cannot integrate this solution in the question's framework because my test environment, the ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE, doesn't come with *slnunicode* and I don't know how to add it.

That was it. If anyone has any doubt or would like further explanations, please, use the comments. I hope it's useful to someone else.